# PHP: How to use a substring to access global variables having a dependent name in a switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement, substring

I have a long list of PHP switch statements that differ only in a substring, such as with strx, stry and strz as shown below:

```
    switch ($block_name) {
            case "strx_blk":
                    $list = &$GLOBALS['strx_list'];
                    $checked = $GLOBALS['strx_checked'];
                    break;
            case "stry_blk":
                    $list = &$GLOBALS['stry_list'];
                    $checked = $GLOBALS['stry_checked'];
                    break;
            case "strz_blk":
                    $list = &$GLOBALS['strz_list'];
                    $checked = $GLOBALS['strz_checked'];
                    break;
    }
```

I would like to know if there a more compact way to express the same logic in PHP. There could be a large number of such repetitions hence the necessity for automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split up `$block_name` and concatenate the prefix to the array indexes.

```
$array = explode('_', $block_name);
$prefix = $array[0];
$list = &$GLOBALS[$prefix . "_list"];
$checked = $GLOBALS[$PREFIX . "_checked"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the gist. `list($prefix) = explode("_", $block_name);` can replace the first two lines I think.

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
$part1 = 'strz';
$part2 = 'list';
var_dump($GLOBALS[$part1 . '_' . $part2]);
```

Comment: But `$part1` changes depending on the value of `$block_name`.